# Firmware from build website hangs after software reset

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I have noticed that after calling `node.restart()` it hangs until the watchdog timer kicks in and resets it again. I've even observed this occurring twice consecutively, i.e., it hangs after calling restart, and then hangs again after the watchdog resets it. The first line of my `init.lua` file is a print statement; when it hangs I don't see that output, so I don't think it's a feature of my code.

Has anyone else observed this?  Is there a way around it?

```
branch: master
build   built on: 2016-03-15 10:39
powered by Lua 5.1.4 on SDK 1.4.0
modules:     adc,bit,file,gpio,i2c,net,node,pwm,rtcfifo,rtcmem,rtctime,sntp,tmr,uart,wifi
```

Comment: Never experience something like this personally. We'd certainly need to know the branch/revision of your firmware. Also, you should use http://nodemcu.readthedocs.org/en/dev/en/modules/node/#nodebootreason to gain possible further insights.

Comment: When this occurs the reason is always 4, watchdog timer.

Comment: Just tested again with the listed modules against `master` - works for me. Of course we can't know what else is running on your device at the time you call `node.restart()`.